# How to quickly encrypt a password string in Django without an User Model?

Tags: python, django

Based on my current Django app settings, is there a function or a snippet that allows me to view the encrypted password, given a raw string? I am testing some functionality and this would be useful for me.

I am looking for something like:

```
password = encrypt_raw_password("abcdef")
```

Comment: I hope it might be help you. 
see this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/749703/736327

Comment: Sure: [make_password](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/passwords/#django.contrib.auth.hashers.make_password)

Comment: Thank you @mariodev, it is exactly what I was looking for! You should post this as an answer so that I can accept it :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a small util function just for that: [make_password](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/passwords/#django.contrib.auth.hashers.make_password).

Answer (score 8):

You can make use of Django auth hashers:

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password

password = make_password('somepass@123')
```

The version of Django should be **1.8** and above. I have tested in the latest version **Django 3+**

Comment: @Codador Its working for me on Django 3. The minimum required Django version is 1.8.

Answer (score 3):

An update on this question since the previous answer does not seem to be supported.

```
import crypt
# To encrypt the password. This creates a password hash with a random salt.
password_hash = crypt.crypt(password)

# To check the password.
valid_password = crypt.crypt(cleartext, password_hash) == password_hash
```

Source: https://docs.python.org/2/library/crypt.html

Comment: Why do you say ['make_password'](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/passwords/#django.contrib.auth.hashers.make_password) isn't supported? It's still in the docs for Django 1.9.